# probability density function of linear transformation singular

Tags: probability

Suppose $y = Ax$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a fixed matrix, and $x$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $m < n$. The probability density function (pdf) of $x$, $f(x)$, is known. How do we find the pdf of $y$ noting that the matrix $A$ is singular?? One obvious thing is that the density of $y$ will have a mass at $y=0$, where $P(y=0) = P(x\in N(A))$, where $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$. I am still unclear how to determine this pdf given that $A$ is not invertible.